# spin locks in ebpf. what this error instruction dump means and how to use spin lock

Tags: c, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I like to test this function `bpf_spin_lock` in ebpf kernel program.

This is my code

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/ipv6.h>
#include <linux/icmpv6.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>
/* Defines xdp_stats_map from packet04 */
#include "../common/xdp_stats_kern_user.h"
#include "../common/xdp_stats_kern.h"
#include <../common/parsing_helpers.h>


#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

#define ETH_ALEN 6

#define MAX_ENTRIES 1000

/*struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY_OF_MAPS);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, __u64);
    __uint(max_entries, MAX_ENTRIES);
} hash_map SEC(".maps");
*/

struct hash_elem {
    int cnt;
    struct bpf_spin_lock lock;
};
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, struct hash_elem);
    __uint(max_entries, 100);
} hash_map SEC(".maps");
struct a{struct bpf_spin_lock lock;};

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, long);
    __uint(max_entries, 2);
} hash_map1 SEC(".maps");
//static __u32 i=0;



SEC("xdp")
int  xdp_prog_simple(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{

    
        struct hash_elem val;   
        bpf_spin_lock(&val.lock);
        
        
        val.cnt++;

        bpf_spin_unlock(&val.lock);
          bpf_map_update_elem(&hash_map, &val.cnt, &val, BPF_ANY);
    
    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

But to load program there is error

```
libbpf: load bpf program failed: Permission denied
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
; bpf_spin_lock(&val.lock);
0: (bf) r6 = r10
1: (07) r6 += -4
; bpf_spin_lock(&val.lock);
2: (bf) r1 = r6
3: (85) call bpf_spin_lock#93
R1 type=fp expected=map_value
processed 4 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

libbpf: -- END LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'xdp'
libbpf: failed to load object './k.o'
ERR: loading BPF-OBJ file(./k.o) (-22): Invalid argument
ERR: loading file: ./k.o
```

The last line of function instructions are

```
; bpf_spin_lock(&val.lock);
2: (bf) r1 = r6
3: (85) call bpf_spin_lock#93
    R1 type=fp expected=map_value
```

is it saying bpf_spin_lock expects map? but this makes no sense, or correct me if its saying something, what the error means and the function assembly language dump
Can I use spin lock from the api in ebpf/xdp programs?

Comment: It expects a `map_value`, a value from your map. Although `val` has the right type from a C point of view, when you pass it to the `bpf_spin_lock()` helper, it does not point to a map value yet. You want to initialise it first: `val = bpf_map_lookup_elem(...); if (!val) return; bpf_spin_lock(&val.lock); ...`

Comment: @Qeole but when I use `bpf_map_lookup_elem` then if condition `if (!val)` does not pass so my spin lock code remains not executed

Comment: @Qeole does calling bpf_map_lookup_elem in this code , in that case do I need to call bpf_map_update_elem with some key and that some key I need to provide to bpf_map_lookup_elem

Comment: If you get `NULL` because the entry doesn't exist, I think you can just call `bpf_map_update_elem()` to create your entry. This helper uses a RCU so I don't think you need to protect it with a spinlock. Then once your entry is created, later runs can grab the entry with the `bpf_map_lookup_elem()`, lock the variable, edit the content of the value by using the pointer (e.g. `val->cnt = foo(cnt) + 1;`) or run whatever critical section they need to, and at last release the lock.